# Cannot resolve package when referencing Git library with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalacheck

I'm trying to reference a custom ScalaCheck with Git, my `build.sbt` file is as follow

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "myproject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(/*other dependencies*/)
  )
  .dependsOn(sc)

lazy val sc = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/<user>/scalacheck.git"))
version in sc := "1.14.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

The problem is that I can't import the library. I only get an error that scalacheck is not a part of `org`. This is my code

```
import org.scalacheck._
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello world")
}
```

Also, this far I only get if I use Scala version 2.12, but I need to use 2.11 as some other dependencies only support that. Using 2.11 it can't resolve the dependency at all.

I'm at SBT version 0.13.13.

This is my sbt output,

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\user\myproject\project
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\user\.sbt\0.13\staging\ec35d052aa233b07b77a\scalacheck\project
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/C:/Users/user/myproject/)
> [info] Defining root/*:shellPrompt
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/C:/Users/user/myproject/)
[info] Defining */*:sbtStructureOutputFile
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/C:/Users/user/myproject/)
[info] Defining */*:sbtStructureOptions
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/C:/Users/user/myproject/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from C:/Users/user/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-0.13.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/C:/Users/user/myproject/)
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/user/myproject/}root...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving default#scalacheck_2.11;1.14.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Resolving default#scalacheck_2.11;1.14.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: default#scalacheck_2.11;1.14.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\user\.ivy2\local\default\scalacheck_2.11\1.14.0-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/default/scalacheck_2.11/1.14.0-SNAPSHOT/scalacheck_2.11-1.14.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving org.scalaj#scalaj-http_2.11;2.3.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-scala_2.11;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-paranamer;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.8 ...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.7 ...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.7 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.20 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.scala-logging#scala-logging_2.11;3.5.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.21 ...
[info] Resolving com.softwaremill.quicklens#quicklens_2.11;1.4.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalacheck#scalacheck_2.11;1.13.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: default#scalacheck_2.11;1.14.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      default:scalacheck_2.11:1.14.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]        +- myproject:myproject_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last root/*:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last root/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (root/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: default#scalacheck_2.11;1.14.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] (root/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: default#scalacheck_2.11;1.14.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 2017-feb-10 09:14:53
```

The `.sbt/0.13/staging/ec35d052aa233b07b77a/scalacheck` contains the full repo and what I think is a build in the target directory, but most refers to builds for Scala version 2.12.

Follow-up edit: I think this bug report for SBT is involved https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `<user>/scalacheck.git` is fork of original `rickynils/scalacheck.git`, the problem is that current master branch of scalacheck
is [targetted to scala 2.12.0](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/861f58ef7a5f059da50df502f856d17bfe244bf9/build.sbt#L13)

Since your `scalaVersion` is 2.11.8, the current revision of scalacheck is not supported.

Therefore, changing your `build.sbt`'s `scalaVersion` to 2.12.0 will solve the problem.

Also, you can check that scalacheck contains three project inside it using `sbt projects`:

```
$ sbt projects
  js
  jvm
* scalacheck
```

`js` is for `scalajs`, so what you need is `jvm`

Therefore you have to use `ProjectRef` instead of `RootProject` to specify project.

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "myproject",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.0",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(/*other dependencies*/)
  )
  .dependsOn(sc)

lazy val sc = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/<user>/scalacheck.git"),"jvm")
version in sc := "1.14.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Also changing the `scalaVersion` of `build.sbt` to `2.11.8` in `https://github.com/<user>/scalacheck.git` might work, but it won't compile if it uses new feature of `2.12.0`.

If you want to use scala 2.11.8, it is possible to specify old version using `#GIT_TAG` syntax.

```
ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck.git#1.13.4"),"jvm")
```

Comment: First, wouldn't the `crossScalaVersions` setting in ScalaCheck build.sbt fix this? Second, while sbt do find scalacheck, I still get the import error `scalacheck is not part of org` in Main. Also, instead of using 2.12 (as one of my dependencies need 2.11) can I specify an older ScalaCheck version with sbt?

Comment: @davl I updated the answer, how to specify older scalacheck and fixing import error. And yes, as you say, `crossScalaVersions` is specified in `build.sbt` of scalacheck so it should run in `2.11.8`, but maybe `crossScalaVersions` is not intended to be used for `RootProject` or `ProjectRef`, and only for deploying. I don't know the truth.